# How to save action table in pybrain

Tags: python, pybrain

I want to use Pybrain Reinforcement Learning to build a AI to play a game.
I use [Reinforcement Learning](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/reinforcement-learning.html),
it will generate a action value table. But i don't know how to save it, and read after i train it.

I have found how to save the network in pybrain, but it can not save the action-value table.

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.tools.customxml import NetworkWriter
from pybrain.tools.customxml import NetworkReader

net = buildNetwork(4,6,1)

NetworkWriter.writeToFile(net, 'filename.xml')
net = NetworkReader.readFrom('filename.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.getActionValues(<row>)` method:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pybrain.rl.learners.valuebased import ActionValueTable

a = ActionValueTable(5, 5)
a.initialize(0.)

table = []
for i in range(a.numRows):
    table.append(a.getActionValues(i))

print(str(table))
```